# Name a column added with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

l have the following csv file that l process as follow

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',   sep=',',header=None)

id                                       ocr    raw_value
00037625-4706-4dfe-a7b3-de8c47e3a28d    A       3
000a7b30-4c4f-4756-a757-f688ccc55d5d    A       /c
000b08e3-4129-4fd2-8ec0-23d00fe38a45    A      yes
00196436-12bc-4024-b623-25bac586d314    A      know
001b8c43-3e73-43c1-ba4f-df5edb10dfac    A      hi
002882ca-48bb-4161-a75a-cf0ec984d650    A      fd
003b2890-3727-4c79-955a-f74ec6945ed7    A     Sensible
004d9025-86f0-4f8c-9720-01e3385c5e77    A      2015
```

Now l want to add a new column :

```
df['val']=None
for img in images:
     id, ext = img.rsplit('.',1)
     idx = df[df[0] ==id].index.values
     df.loc[df.index[idx], 'val'] =  id
```

When l write df in a new file as follow :

```
df.to_csv('new_file.csv', sep=',',encoding='utf-8')
```

l noticed that the column is correctly added and filled. But the column remains without name and it's supposed to be named `val`

```
id                                       ocr    raw_value
00037625-4706-4dfe-a7b3-de8c47e3a28d    A       3            4
000a7b30-4c4f-4756-a757-f688ccc55d5d    A       /c           3
000b08e3-4129-4fd2-8ec0-23d00fe38a45    A      yes           1 
00196436-12bc-4024-b623-25bac586d314    A      know          8 
001b8c43-3e73-43c1-ba4f-df5edb10dfac    A      hi            9
002882ca-48bb-4161-a75a-cf0ec984d650    A      fd            10
003b2890-3727-4c79-955a-f74ec6945ed7    A     Sensible       14
```

How to set set to the last column added ?

EDIT1:

```
print(df.head())

                                     0     1       2           3
0                                   id    ocr  raw_value  manual_raw_value   
1  00037625-4706-4dfe-a7b3-de8c47e3a28d  ABBYY         03                03   
2  000a7b30-4c4f-4756-a757-f688ccc55d5d  ABBYY        y/c               y/c   
3  000b08e3-4129-4fd2-8ec0-23d00fe38a45  ABBYY    armoire           armoire   
4  00196436-12bc-4024-b623-25bac586d314  ABBYY      point             point   

       val  
0      None  
1        93  
2       yic  
3   armoire  
4     point
```

Comment: It is interesting, it should works. What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` before `to_csv` ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  But on a separate note, it is bad practice to use `id` as a variable in your code.  You are overloading the baked-in function `id()`.

Comment: @jezrael, it returns [0, 1, 2, 3, 'val']  the header for pandas

Comment: And if `print (df.head())` before `to_csv` there is no `column` too?

Comment: your use of `df[0]` makes me suspect the first row of your `DataFrame` is not an index, and that the `to_csv` doesn't include the column labels. add `header=0` to your call to `read_csv` to correct this

Comment: @jezrael, PLEASE see edite 1

Comment: @vincent75 - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need only [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), because `sep=','` is by default and can be omit and `header=None` is used if `csv` have no header:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Problem is your first row was not parsed to columns names, but to first data row.

Comment: when l save it df.to_csv('new_file') it adds a new column index in the beginning which represent pandas indexes how to remove that column ?

Comment: Need `df.to_csv('new_file', index=False)` for remove first index column.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',   sep=',', header=0, index_col=0)
```

should allow you to simplify the next portion to

```
df['val']=None
for img in images:
     image_id, ext = img.rsplit('.',1)
     df.loc[image_id, 'val'] =  image_id
```

If you don't need the `image_id` as index afterwards, use `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

one easy way...
before to_csv:

```
df.columns.value[3]="val"
```

Comment: the first row of the `DataFrame` the OP pasted is are not the column labels, but the first row of his actual `DataFrame`, so changing the column labels will not help much